# ActiveRecord / Rails - Access model instance variable that is overridden by a module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Suppose we have an ActiveRecord model `Group` which has a property (and column in database) called `name` (it is actually not visible by default):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  include App::CustomModule
end
```

Also there is a custom module `CustomModule` included into a `Group` model, which has a method called `name`:

```
module App
  module CustomModule
    def name
      'module name'
    end
  end
end
```

As a result, when referencing to a `name` inside of a `Group` model instance I get a value from a `CustomModule`'s `name` method (the same is for `self.name`):

```
> Group.find(1).name
=> "module name"
```

How can I get a value for original `name` property of `Group` model instance  (not module method value) without changing the names of both class property and module method?

*rails (4.0.4) activerecord (4.0.4)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
group.read_attribute(:name)
```